# SQL if statement to fix issue

Tags: postgresql, if-statement, case

I have this select

```
insert into test(t_name)
(select users.first_name || '_' || users.last_name 
|| '_' || to_date($values.report_date, 'YYYY.MM.DD')
from users where users.id = $session.user_id)
```

which works as supposed, except I want it if users.first_name/users.last_name are null and user_id=0 to insert another string 'admin' otherwise I get error because it violates not-null constraint on column t_name.

Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a CASE in the SELECT part:

```
insert into test (t_name) 
select case 
         when users.first_name is null and users.last_name is null and users.id=0 then 'admin'
         else users.first_name || '_' || users.last_name || '_' || to_date($values.report_date,'YYYY.MM.DD')
       end 
from users
where users.id = $session.user_id
```

It's not clear (to me) from the question if all conditions you mentioned have to be true or just one of them. Depending on what you want, you should change the `AND`s to `OR`s in the first `WHEN` part.

(Note that there is no need to enclose the SELECT in `()` for an `INSERT ... SELECT` statement)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MySQL you can use IFNULL.

```
INSERT INTO test(t_name)
(
    SELECT IFNULL(users.first_name || '_' || users.last_name || '_' || to_date($values.report_date, 'YYYY.MM.DD'), 'admin')
    FROM users
    WHERE users.id = $session.user_id
)
```

In MSSQL there is a similar `ISNULL` function, I assume that there is likewise solutions for other database systems.

Comment: I tried the above solution and it worked. Nevertheless, +1 for your time.